# How many ways to arrange 3 elephants, 1 lion, 2 rabbits, 1 bird

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many ways to arrange 3 elephants, 1 lion, 2 rabbits, 1 bird that
> no elephant sit next to a lion? (assuming all the animals from same
> type are identical

I thought of approach the way of, All possibilities  - (The possibility we don't want).

I took 2 cases where

Case 1 : elephant, lion ,elephant

Case 2: x, lion, elephant , x is different than an elephant

since it doesnt matter where the 3rd elephant in 2 cases

then take the elephant and the lion as one object

finally $\frac{7!}{3!2!}- (case 1 + 2*case2)$

multiply case 2 by two since one elephant can sit on both sides on the lion

Comment: Your strategy is sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem deserves exposition.  First of all, I agree with N.F.Taussig: "strategy is sound".

However, there is a great deal to discuss on this problem:

Next, the initial term of $420 = \frac{7!}{(3!)(2!)}$ indicates that the seating is in a **row**, not a circle.

This indicates that you actually have 3 Inclusion-Exclusion cases to deal with, rather than 2.

**Case-1**
The lion is at one of the two ends, and has an elephant for a neighbor.

There are two end-seats (left or right) to choose from.  Further, there are then $\binom{5}{2} \times \binom{3}{2}$ ways of distributing the 5 remaining animals.

Therefore, the enumeration for case 1 is:

$$2 \times 10 \times 3 = 60.$$

**Case 2**

There are 5 middle seats that the lion might be in, and the lion has an elephant on both sides.  The rabbits can therefore be distributed in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways around the remaining seats, and there are then 2 choices for the remaining elephant.

Therefore, the enumeration for case 2 is:

$$5 \times 6 \times 2 = 60.$$

**Case 3**

There are 5 middle seats that the lion might be in, and the lion has an elephant on one side only.  There are 5 seats for the lion to choose, and then 2 ways for determining whether the elephant is on the lion's left or right.

If the lion's other neighbor is the bear, then there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of distributing the remaining two elephants and two rabbits.

If the lion's other neighbor is a rabbit, then there are $\binom{4}{2} \times 2$ ways of distributing the remaining 4 animals.

Therefore, the enumation for Case 3 is

$$5 \times 2 \times [6 + 12] = 180.$$

Consequently the Inclusion-Exclusion approach yields the answer of

$$420 - 60 - 60 - 180 = 120.$$

---

**Now the fun starts**.  Is this (**indirect** - Inclusion Exclusion) approach the best way of calculating the answer.  A case can be made either way.  In general, Inclusion Exclusion approaches **generalize well**, which means that for more complicated problems, the approach is best.

This means that one does well to master this approach.  **However**, in this case, the **direct approach**, which is given below, is easier.

**Case A**
The lion is on one of the two end seats, and has either a rabbit or a bear for a neighbor.  The factor of $2$ indicates that the lion could be on either end.

If the neighbor is the bear, then the enumeration is $\binom{5}{3}$, re placing the elephants.  If instead, the neighbor is a rabbit, then the enumeration is $\binom{5}{3} \times 2$.

Therefore, the enumeration for Case A is

$$2 \times 10 \times (1 + 2) = 60.$$

**Case B** 
The lion could be in any of the 5 middle seats, which yields a first factor of $5$.  There are then 3 choices for the lion's left-right neighbors : rlr, rlb, or blr.  Regardless of which of these 3 choices pertain, 3 of the 4 remaining animals will be the elephants, so the possible distribution will then be $\binom{4}{3}.$

Therefore, the enumeration for Case B is

$$5 \times 3 \times 4 = 60.$$

Therefore, the direct approach, which merely adds Case A and Case B gives

$$60 + 60 = 120.$$